# Log issue in windows server 12

Tags: windows

I am able to find schedlgu.txt in C:\WINDOWS\Tasks in windows server 2003 but I am unable to find schedlgu.txt in windows server 2012.
Please help me where it consist.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: This does not sound like a question about programming. If this is not about programming, a different site would be appropriate.

Comment: schedlgu.txt has the logs actually I need same in windows server 2012